# Looking for a Google post on "How much time does it take do to X"

Tags: latency

I remember reading a post by someone at Google with several ballpark statistics such as how much time does it take to:

- Obtain a lock
- Read/write a piece of data from registers, memory, disk, remote disk
- Fetch a page
- ...

(Don't catch me on the exact statistics). Can you help me find this post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not the original article that I had in mind, but [this article](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,4db70333-295b-441f-80f9-21b90bd44287.aspx) does give order of magnitudes for several of these operations.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you're looking for, but Steve Souders of Google maintains a blog and touches on some of these web app performance topics in many of his posts: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/

His [latest post](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/) on John Rauser (Amazon)'s presentation at Velocity 2010 may be of interest to you.

**Edit:** You'll also be able to find on his site a power point presentation on front-end optimization which is pretty interesting and has a lot of tips on how to make your site load (or appear to load) faster.